# How to avoid matplotlib to simplify my Y axis in figure?

Tags: matplotlib

the image of what I mean in my question

[image: 1]

I'm using BMP280 to measure Temperature and Pressure using Raspberry.

I'm using matplotlib to make a graph, but the matplotlib simplify my Y axis bi adding +9.967e2.

is there any way to avoid matplotlib simplify my Y axis. Sorry I'm new to this so I don't know much.

I tried to search in google but I don't find anything. Maybe I'm using the wrong keyword as I don't know what should I search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn off the offset as shown in the examples [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/scalarformatter.html). For example, if you've made you plot with:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot(x, y)
```

then you can turn off the offset with

```
ax = plt.gca()  # get the axes object

# turn off the offset (on the y-axis only)
ax.ticklabel_format(axis="y", useOffset=False)

plt.show()
```

See the [`ticklabel_format`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html) docs for more info.